# Search Bars and Buttons in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I'm currently making a website using PHP, HTML and a classless CSS (Water.css) Right now, I have a problem aligning my search bars and buttons into a row

```
<!-- Search Bar Name-->
    <form action="search.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search Equipment">
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form>

<!-- Search Bar Price-->
    <form action="searchprice.php" method="post">
        <label for="min_price">Minimum price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="min_price" id="min_price">
        <label for="max_price">Maximum price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>


    <button onclick="window.location='add_equipment.php'">Add Equipment</a></button>
```

The search bars and the button work perfectly fine, however I have no clue why it stacks up like a column instead of being in a row.

It would be nice if someone could help me with this, I am a newbie to HTML

[image: An image of the search bar, minimum price to maximum price search, and 'add equipment' button is in a column instead of being in a row]

Comment: You should learn more about display block, flex and grid in css, also you can use position (relative and absolute together) in your case, could you add a snippet of your html and css codes so I can edit it and fix it for you?

Comment: @Amirhoseinh73 sure, [here](https://pastebin.com/pq3wQhE4) you go!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:
Like Amir said lots of information on using divs,flex,grid in css. I feel like the classless link is making your inputs do that everytime I link to it, it puts everything in columns.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <title>Equipments</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" a href="./css/main.css">
    
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/water.min.css"> -->
</head>
 
<body>
<div class="nav">
    <h2>List Of Equipments</h2>
    
    <div class="navs">
        <!-- Search Bar Name-->
            <form action="search.php" method="GET">
                <label for="Search">Search Equipment</label>
                <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search Equipment"><br>
                <input id="Sbutton" type="submit" value="Go">
    
            </form>       
    </div>
    
           
        
        <!-- Search Bar Price-->
    <div class="navs">
            <form action="searchprice.php" method="post">
                <label for="min_price">Minimum price:</label>
                <input type="text" name="min_price" id="min_price"><br>
                <label for="max_price">Maximum price:</label>
                <input type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price"><br>
                <input id="Sbutton2" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
                <button id="Sbutton3" onclick="window.location='add_equipment.php'">Add Equipment</button>
            </form>

            </div>
    
    
            
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS when I am styling I like to change background of each div class so I can get a visual of what is happening as I change code.

```
.nav{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(77, 76, 76);
}
h2{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight:bolder;
}
.navs {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(108, 109, 109);
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top:  10px;
   }
  
  #Sbutton{
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 150%;
    width: 15%;
    margin-left:  15%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
  }
  #Sbutton2{
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 150%;
    width: 15%;
    margin-left:  15%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
  }
  #Sbutton3{
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 150%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    
    
  }
 

  table{
    border:3px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th{
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 6px;
}
td{
    border: 2px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.